# How and why does using redirection or writing files within an if statement affect exit code?

Tags: scripting, zsh, exit-status

In **zsh**

```
echo 'a string' > test.txt
echo $?
0
```

and

```
[[ $(echo 'a string') ]]
echo $?
0
```

whereas

```
[[ $(echo 'a string' > test.txt) ]]
echo $?
1
```

another example

```
curl -so 'curl-8.2.1.tar.gz' https://curl.se/download/curl-8.2.1.tar.gz
echo $?
0
```

or

```
[[ $(curl -so 'curl-8.2.1.tar.gz' https://curl.se/download/curl-8.2.1.tar.gz) ]]
echo $?
1
```

My questions:

1. Is this because of output redirection? If no, what is causing this?
2. The commands get executed successfully: `a string` appears in `test.txt` and curl downloads the file to the output file I specified, why does the evaluation result in `false`?
3. Is there a sane way to handle this in scripting? Let's say I want to execute some command if the previous one executed successfully (but returned `false` still), how should one go about it? I could add a second check to see if the line appeared or the file was downloaded, but then the evualation of successful command execution wouldn't be necessary in the first place.

Some more examples for completeness (readability vs. "correctness"?):

```
if ( $(echo 'a string' > text.txt) ); then echo yes; else echo no;fi
yes
```

```
if (( $(echo 'a string' > text.txt) )); then echo yes; else echo no;fi
no
```

```
if $(echo 'a string' > text.txt); then echo yes; else echo no;fi
yes
```

```
if echo 'a string' > text.txt; then echo yes; else echo no;fi
yes
```

Comment: One thing that may apply here, from the [Conditional Expressions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html) part of the `zsh` documentation: _For compatibility, if there is a single argument that is not syntactically significant, typically a variable, the condition is treated as a test for whether the expression expands as a string of non-zero length. In other words, [[ $var ]] is the same as [[ -n $var ]]. It is recommended that the second, explicit, form be used where possible._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `$?`

In the **PARAMETERS SET BY THE SHELL** section of man `zshparam`, or `info zsh 'Parameters Set By The Shell'`  you'll see that, `$?` is the exit status returned by the last command.

#### `$(...)`

In man `zshexpn` or `info zsh 'Command Substitution'` you'll see:

> **COMMAND SUBSTITUTION**
>
> A command enclosed in parentheses preceded by a dollar sign, like
> `'$(...)'`, or quoted with grave accents, like `...`, is
> replaced with its standard output, with any trailing newlines deleted.

So for instance, the expression `$(echo 'a string')` would be replaced with the output of this command (`a string<newline>`) stripped of the trailing newline characters, which gives `a string`. But the command inside `$(echo 'a string' > test.txt)` would produce no output to the standard output, so the result of that expression is an empty string.

#### `[[ ... ]]`

In the man page of `zshmisc` or `info zsh 'Conditional Expressions'`, you'll see:

> **Conditional Expressions**
>
> A conditional expression is used with the `[[` compound command to
> test attributes of files and to compare strings. Each expression can
> be constructed from one or more of the following unary or binary
> expressions:

[...]

> For  compatibility, if there is a single  argument that is not
> syntactically significant, typically a variable,  the condition is
> treated as  **a test for  whether the expression expands as a string of
> non-zero length.**

#### And now for your examples

So in the following line, the output of the command inside the `$( ... )` is the string `a string<newline>` and the expansion of `$(...)` itself will therefore be `a string`, which is a non-zero length string, thus the `[[ ... ]]` evaluation will return true (0 exit status).

```
[[ $(echo 'a string') ]]
```

But in the following command, since you have a redirection, the expansion of `$( ... )` will be a zero-length string, and the `[[ ... ]]` evaluation will return false (exit status 1, being a number other than 0).

```
[[ $(echo 'a string' > test.txt) ]]
```

Similarly, the exit status of the following command is the exit status of the `curl` command.

```
curl -so 'curl-8.2.1.tar.gz' https://curl.se/download/curl-8.2.1.tar.gz
```

And the manpage of `curl` will state under what condition it returns a non-zero (failure) exit status.

But in the next example, the exit status would depend on whether the `curl` command had any output (success) or didn't have any output (failure).

```
[[ $(curl -so 'curl-8.2.1.tar.gz' https://curl.se/download/curl-8.2.1.tar.gz) ]]
```

I'll stop here, but you can continue reading the manual, for example the meaning of `(( ... ))` in the **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION** section of man `zshmisc` (or `info zsh 'Arithmetic Evaluation'`)

Comment: This explanation is comprehensible. However, regarding the curl example, it does not seem entirely correct. When removing the "-s" flag (silent = no output), curl outputs a progress meter and this does not return `0`. Only when both flags, -s and -o, are removed, the condition returns `0`, even though its output seemingly is the same.

Comment: @pming  Notice that _"A command enclosed in parentheses preceded by a dollar sign [...] **is replaced with its standard output**"_. The progress meter goes to standard **error**, not to standard **output**. When you use the `-o` flag, `curl` will (as stated in its man page) _"Write output to <file> instead of stdout."_, so the expansion will be a zero-length string. When you remove the flag, `curl` will do what it states in the manual: _"If not told otherwise, curl writes the received data to stdout."_, so than the expression is expanded to the data received by `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

I conclude from this that using `[[ ... ]]` is not suitable for evaluating successful command execution, unless successful command execution is understood in a way such that the command's output results in a non-zero string. For the purpose of verification in zsh scripting, the right way would be to

0. (use `if command; then ...; [else ...;] fi` as stated by muru's comment)
1. run the command on its own and check its exit code with `$?` afterwards, and / or
2. verify if the actual output of the command, for example by examining the contents of the files that were generated by it

Comment: If the command's exit status can be relied on, then what you should use is just`if command args ; then ... ; fi`, e.g., `if grep -q something some/file; then some other thing ; fi`